# Why are the threads in these two methods different?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Take a look at the code below.

Here I create a thread, set its name, and start it:

```
Private Sub fileCreated(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Dim processFileThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf fileCreatedHelper)
    processFileThread.Name = e.FullPath
    processFileThread.Start()
End Sub
```

This is the sub that is the thread:

```
Private Sub fileCreatedHelper()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf fileCreatedHelper))
    Else
        Dim currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread ' NOT WORKING!
        Dim fileName = currentThread.Name
        ' do more stuff that requires fileName
    End If
End Sub
```

In `fileCreatedHelper`, `Thread.CurrentThread` doesn't get me the thread that I created above. Why is this? When I put breakpoints in and look at their `ManagedThreadIds`, they are different.

Ideas/thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you're in the ELSE branch, you have been invoked and CurrentThread is the main (GUI) thread. Not the Thread you created in step 1.

You will need an extra method:

- one to process the file on a separate Thread. Consider another mecahnism to pass the filename.
- one to 'use' the results in the GUI. That one need the InvokeReq/Invoke pattern.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `New Thread(...).Start()`, you're creating a new thread.

By calling `Me.Invoke(...)`, you're executing your code on the UI thread, and making the new thread wait for the code on the UI thread to finish.